# The description for Event ID (560) in Source (security) cannot be found. with users in specified group

Tags: permissions, eventviewer, security

I have some users in a group that look at the audits. They are in a group I created. This group should have permissions to view the security audits. They can see them, but the descriptions are missing. If I log in as admin, it looks ok. So it's some type of permission issue. I already checked the `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security permissions` and it has Full Control from Administrators and Full Control for SYSTEM. The Local Security setting is set, so they can manage and view the security audits as well.

These are standalone machines and there are other machines like these that do work fine. The only difference would be MSSQL is installed on the ones that DO NOT work.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?